# How to set default value from url browser in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a URL: https://local.test/real-price?city_id=2

Vue template

```
<template>
   <ul>
      <li
          v-for="city in states"
          :key="city.id"
          :id="city.id"
          v-bind:class="{ active: (city.id === city_id) }"
       >
          {{ city.name }}
       </li>
  </ul>
</template>
<script>
export default {
   data: function() {
        return {
            states: [],
            city_id: 0,
        };
   },
   created() {
      this.states = [{id: 1, name: "City A"}, {id: 2, name: "City B"}, {id: 3, name: "City C"}];
   },
   mounted() {
      this.city_id = this.$route.query.city_id ? this.$route.query.city_id : 0
   },
}
</script>
```

Result not auto add class "active" when `city_id=2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `city_id` variable is a **number** in your code while it's a **string** in the url.

Try parsing it in your `mounted`

```js
this.city_id = this.$route.query.city_id ? parseInt(this.$route.query.city_id) : 0
```

Comment: thanks u, your answer is exactly

Answer (score 0):

Another way of solving this is to use `==`

```
v-bind:class="{ active: (city.id == city_id) }"
```